# How to set the FontStyle of a TextBlock via Binding (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My snipped code of the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" FontStyle="{Binding FontStyleTreeItem}"/>
```

Snipped code Class TreeItem:

```
public System.Windows.FontStyles FontStyleTreeItem {get;set}
```

I want to assign the property "FontStyleTreeItem" something like:

```
treeItem.FontStyleTreeItem = System.Windows.FontStyles.Italic;
```

But this doesn't work because "System.Windows.FontStyles" is static. But I can't figure out how to give a good solution to set the above property.

I also tried to set the property as a FontStyle, so without the **s** at the end (FontStyle**s**), but then the fontstyle of the textblock doesn't change.

```
public FontStyle FontStyleTreeItem { get { return FontStyle.Italic; } }
```

Can somebody see what I'm missing?

Already thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the property should be `System.Windows.FontStyle`. It may still return a static value such as `FontStyles.Italic`:

```
public System.Windows.FontStyle FontStyleTreeItem { get { return System.Windows.FontStyles.Italic; } }
```

If you define the property like this:

```
public System.Windows.FontStyle FontStyleTreeItem { get; set; }
```

...you can set it to any `FontStyle` value, e.g.:

```
FontStyleTreeItem = FontStyles.Italic;
```

If you set it dynamically at runtime, you need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface for the font style to change.

Comment: But how can I set this property, that is the question?

Comment: Like you would set any other property. Please see my edit. `FontStyles.Italic` returns a `FontStyle`.

Comment: Aha, sorry (to quick). Thanks.